How does google calculate keyword density of a webpage
I am trying to run events and I'm managing my own website as well as some content on an event website.
Both sites also have schema in json-ld format.
I tried a couple keyword scanners and I manually look at the keywords in the source of each page and the results are vastly different.
How is keyword density actually calculated?
Does google simply scan for the word (regardless of if its in HTML code or not)? or does it do some special parsing first?

Google never told anywhere how they count the keyword density, and I think they will never publish this kind of thing.
Below is the way you can calculate the keyword density on each page of your website.
"Divide the number of times a keyword is used on your page by the total number of words on the page."
As per my understanding, Google and other search engines also do not count words/keywords. Because this is not the only ranking factor that search engines count. Yes, years ago keyword stuffing used to work perfectly but those times are gone.
